# Is it elementary substructure

Tags: logic

$$\langle P(N), \subseteq\rangle \prec \langle P(R), \subseteq\rangle $$

Is it an elementary substructure?

A substructure $N$ of structure $M$ is called an elementary substructure of $M$, if for every formula $\varphi$, and for every $$b_1,\ldots,b_n\in N:N \models \varphi(b_1,\ldots,b_n) \Longleftrightarrow M \models \varphi(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$$

How can we show it?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not. Can you think of a property the set $\mathbb{N}$ has as an element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, which it *doesn't* have as an element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$?

That said, they are elementarily *equivalent* - this can be proved easily using [Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game). So this constitutes yet another example of the fact that a substructure which is elementarily equivalent to the whole, need not be an elementary substructure (a simpler counterexample is $[0, 1]$ versus $[0, 2]$ as linear orders).

Comment: I can't. I think that all elements form P(N) are in P(R) too. So there is no idea what property it could be

Comment: @SergeyEsipenko Yes, every element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is an element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. But that doesn't mean they all have the same *properties*. HINT: Suppose $Y\in\mathcal{P}(X)$. What can you say about $Y$ and $X$, in terms of $\subseteq$?

Comment: You mean something like number of elemets? In Y less or equal elements then in X

Comment: @SergeyEsipenko Not really, but sort of. Is there an expression you can write down involving $X, Y$, and $\subseteq$ which you know is true if $Y\in\mathcal{P}(X)$? Put another way: what does it *mean* for $Y$ to be an element of $\mathcal{P}(X)$?

Comment: $$\exists x \in P(x) (y \subseteq x)$$

Comment: The sentence I was looking for was "$Y\subseteq X$" - if $Y$ is an element of the powerset of $X$, then $Y\subseteq X$ by definition. What you've written sort of looks like this, but doesn't really parse (do you see why? the "$\exists x\in P(x)$" is really not supposed to be there). OK, now think about the formula $\varphi(a)=$"$\forall x(x\subseteq a)$." In $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),$ do we have $\varphi(\mathbb{N})$? What about in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Hm
So, if we chose $a=P(N)$, then every $x\subseteq a$
But if $P(R)$ there are elements $\notin P(N)$ and this is not an elementary elementary substructure ??